# SignalR, JQuery and Node

Tags: jquery, signalr, signalr.client

In a project I'm currently working on, we are using Electron as a host.  In the Electron main process, which is a normal Node process we need to connect to a downstream back-end that has SignalR endpoints.

However, since SignalR is a JQuery module and neither SignalR nor JQuery are supported on Node, we're a bit stuck.  I see the following options:

1. Look at some of the JQuery implementations in [node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js) and since
   we use webpack, inject that instead of the normal JQuery into
   SignalR
2. Use an unsupported (and old) [Node version of SignalR](https://github.com/maartenba/SignalR.Node)
3. Have an invisible hidden browser window which will host the SignalR and JQuery bits and proxy them through to the main process over IPC
4. Compile JQuery myself, including only the modules that SignalR require
5. Something else, which you kind people will help me with. :)

Number 1 and 2 scare me as I don't want to be debugging API differences or just plain bugs in the implementations.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-client. He is looking for contributors. After some improvment may be signalr community helps I like open source :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing a dependency on jsdom and providing a dom to jquery via that seems to do the trick:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom, document = jsdom('<html></html>');
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.window.WebSocket = require("ws");
```

If the above is imported before the signalr script, it works fine.

UPDATE: need to make WebSockets available on window object so websockets transport will work

Good luck with it ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for this: `global.window.WebSocket = require("ws");`