# Which is the best solution for using SignalR in electron?

Tags: signalr, electron

Which is the best solution for implementing SignalR **client** in electron?

Should I use [signalr-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-client) or [signalrjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234624/signalr-jquery-and-node) with a hack as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234624/signalr-jquery-and-node)?

It's ok to use only websockets.